# Drupal not using #weight when inserting form elements with form_alter

Tags: 8

I'm inserting an Ajax element into the node_add form, but it always goes to the end, even though the weights are set in the order I want them to be.  It feels reminiscent of this issue from D7:

https://www.drupal.org/node/893392

...But form['#info'] doesn't seem to exist anymore.  What, in D8, could be preventing the form from rendering the form elements in order of ascending weight?

Comment: Is the form AJAX? Hard to tell without seeing some code. But the form should be rebuilt on any #ajax callback, which you might be missing.

Comment: MOST LIKELY your ajax wrapper does not cover all elements.